# Do Python module imports depend on how the code is run?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I don't think any language causes as much headache as python in so simple a thing as importing other source files. So here is the question:
Do my module imports need to depend on how the code is supposed to run?

I have the following directory structure:

```
./__init__.py
./config.py
./kmer
./kmer/__init__.py
./kmer/__main__.py
./kmer/__pycache__
./kmer/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
./kmer/__pycache__/__main__.cpython-36.pyc
./kmer/__pycache__/bed.cpython-36.pyc
./kmer/__pycache__/config.cpython-36.pyc
./kmer/__pycache__/reference.cpython-36.pyc
./kmer/__pycache__/sets.cpython-36.pyc
./kmer/bed.py
./kmer/config.py
./kmer/reference.py
./kmer/sets.py
```

I wish to import a module inside the `khmer` from another module inside the `kmer` package. Simple?

So I add this at the of the `bed.py`:

```
import reference
import config
import sets
```

Now thing will work just fine if I run `python bed.py` ***from the `kmer` directory***. Also things are fine if I come back one directory and call `python kmer/bed.py`. Seems like python searches for imported modules relative to the given file.

Again running it as `python -m bed` from the `kmer` directory works fine but coming back one directory and running `python -m kmer.bed` results in module errors. Here it seem like python looks for modules inside the interpreter's current directory which could be anywhere on the file system so imports relative to it shouldn't work.

This basically means that the imports should depend on how the code is going to be run which makes no sense. I'd appreciate some explanation on how this is supposed to work.

I've looked at quite a lot of resources including the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) question which although very detailed (one of the best descriptions I've found actually) doesn't solve my problem and also doesn't provide proper examples.

Update: I believe this question is more focused on a different aspect of relative import, more precisely how different methods of running the code affect the imports, than the one it is marked as a duplicate of. Thats why I mentioned the other question in first place. Hence I don't think this should be a duplicate.

Comment: You're going to have to explain how the linked question doesn't solve your problem, because it looks to me like it solves your problem.

Comment: @user2357112 What makes this question different is the mixing up package and script semantics part which the Davis's answer below points out. I didn't quite get that from the linked question and understanding is, naturally, subjective.

Answer (score 2):

When writing a package, you must consistently treat it as a package.  First, that means using relative imports within the package: write `from . import reference` in `bed.py`.

It also means the answer for how to access it is always the same: put the directory *containing* `kmer` onto `sys.path` (usually via `PYTHONPATH`).  This is true even if *running* some module in the package as the script, so it must be `python -m kmer.bed`.

Unfortunately, it's a bad idea to run a module inside a package as a script: the module's file is still eligible to be imported **again** under its proper name (rather than the `__main__` used the first time).  The only robust solution is to write a `__main__.py` and run the *package* as the script, avoiding overloading a public module name.

Finally, don't pay much attention to the "feature" of Python putting the script's directory on `sys.path`.  This is useless other than for toy problems where you don't care about name collisions, since any script whose directory would be useful on `sys.path` is necessarily a module (except in case of tricks like making its name not be an identifier).  Moreover, if you want your library to be available to scripts installed elsewhere, it needs to get on `sys.path` some other way anyway.

Comment: Trying to run one of the modules inside the package with the `-m` flag still gives me `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded` error. Doesn't this contradict what you said?

Comment: @Parsoa: What command line did you use?  Was that the full exception message?